# Vite + Vue app file watch, rebuild not works on docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, vite

there is a `{ usePolling: true }` option in the Vite documentation. If I activate this, yes filewatch works.

However, this time the container cannot be closed at all and docker crashes.

Can anyone help with this?

Here are the relevant codes below

Compose

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app-js
    ports:
      - "3035:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    init: true
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

vite.config.js

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],
    build: {
        assetsDir: '.',
        assetsInlineLimit: 0,
        assetsInclude: ['**/*'], 
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: 'src/main.js',
            },
            output: {
                entryFileNames: 'main.js',
                chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
                assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]', 
            },
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        port: 3000,
        host: true,
        strictPort: true,
    }
})
```

Comment: `However, this time the container cannot be closed at all and docker crashes.` What do you mean?

Comment: Exactly same thing. You cannot stop container and docker not works anymore until you restart computer. But i set interval: 1000, and right now i think works good but i am not sure. Still trying.

Comment: Does it work if you don't use Docker, and just run `npm run dev` on your host system?

Comment: Yes only docker crashes